# cypress.io getting docker build environment variables

Tags: javascript, docker, environment-variables, cypress, virtual-environment

If I have a project setup with docker, using a .env that has the docker environment variables defined.  How would I retrieve them while running cypress.io test spec?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the official documentation https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env You have to prefix your variables with `CYPRESS_`.

So for example if your .env file has `CYPRESS_HOST=manz.com`, you can access it in your tests as `Cypress.env('HOST')`.